# Nonsense sentences with だ

Tags: particle-は, copula, は-and-が, subjects, topic

I recently encountered these sentences which must be nonsense because AはBだ means 'A is B'.

> 私は１０５号室だ
>
> 「ノルウェーの森」は村上春樹だ
>
> 東京は初めてだ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148968/discussion-between-karl-knechtel-and-n-hunt).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148975/discussion-on-question-by-n-hunt-nonsense-sentences-with-); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

> ... which must be nonsense because AはBだ means 'A is B'.

It's not always appropriate to parse such sentences in this fashion.

The topic marker は does not always mark the **subject** of the sentence, the substantive that is directly tied to the verb: sometimes it is instead marking the **topic**, the outermost context of the current phrase.  In 「私は１０５号室だ」, the 「私」 is not the *subject*, which would be directly tied to the copular phrase 「１０５号室だ」, and instead this is the *topic*.  A better translation (in terms of better illustrating the meaning) might be:

> **私は**１０５号室だ
> → **As for me**, it is room 105.

What the "it" is in the English is context-dependent: perhaps the speaker has been asked where they are, or where they think something is located, etc.

An example I've seen crop up multiple times is the sentence 「私はウナギです。」 If we parse 「私」 as the **subject**, this becomes *"I am an eel."*  This might be the correct interpretation -- but that would require a very specific context.    A more likely scenario is that the speaker is at a restaurant, and is either ordering, or telling the server which dish is theirs -- in which case, the 「私」 is the **topic**, further distanced (grammatically, semantically) from the verb, and a more correct translation would be *"As for me, it [my order] is the eel."*  More idiomatically, *"For me, the eel"*, or even *"I've got / I'm getting the eel."*

When evaluating sentences like 「AはBです」, consider whether it makes sense for 「A」 to be the **subject**, or the **topic**.

Comment: But, even if you think if it like that, 'As for me, it is room 105', don't we have the same problem, namely, what is 'it' referring to? It can't be, say, a key, because a key isn't a room.

Comment: @N.Hunt, it's context-dependent, as I explicitly called out above. Are we talking about which hotel rooms each person is in? Are we talking about where each of us last saw a particular person? Etc. etc.

Comment: @N.Hunt, for that matter, in the right context, the "it" could indeed be a key -- Q: "Which keys do we all have?" A: "As for me, it's room 105." → "I've got [the key for] room 105." English also has highly context-dependent ways of saying things. "I've got three" could mean that the person has three things, or 3 is the answer to an arithmetic problem, or 3 is the number on their shirt, etc. etc.

Comment: The most logical implied subject for "as for me, [] is room 105" is something like "the room I am staying in".

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Yes, you are quite right that we have the same phenomenon in English---even the original ウナギ文, 僕はうなぎだ readily translates to the English context. Similar to your (reverse) derivation, I would suggest that surface 私は１０５号室だ is derived from (one possible) 私は１０５号室[に泊まっているの]だ. Lest you baulk at the idea that what is elided is not a proper constituent of the sentence (here, I have included に), there are other examples where が or を is clearly elided: 彼はあすから講義だ <— 彼はあすから講義[が始まるの]だ, 今度は子供にみかんだ <— 今度は子供にみかん[をあげるの]だ.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you for providing a useful expansion of 私は１０５号室だ.

Answer (score 1):

These make sense.

私は１０５号室だ -- I'm in room 105.

東京は初めてだ -- It was the first time in Tokyo.

「ノルウェーの森」は村上春樹だ -- [The author of] Norwegian Wood is Haruki Murakami.

Technically, the meaning could be something different.  These sentences sound like answers to question.

So, you have to imagine what kind of question was asked.

For 私は１０５号室だ, it would seem that the speaker was asked which room they were in, or which office is theirs, or something similar.

For 東京は初めてだ, this could be the response to a great variety of questions.  This could be a question about a trip you took.  This could be a question about where and when the 1964 Olympics took place.

For「ノルウェーの森」は村上春樹だ, you could imagine a question like "Who is the author of Norwegian Wood and Kitchen?"  The person asked may not know who the author of Kitchen is but they know that Haruki Murakmai is the author of Norwegian Wood.

AはBだ doesn't technically mean "A is B".  It marks "A" as the topics and then tells you something about "A" which is "B".

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148973/discussion-on-answer-by-a-ellett-nonsense-sentences-with-); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.